# How can I avoid the error from mySQL on mysql_result?

Tags: php, mysql

I get the mysql result using

```
$back = mysql_result($query, 0);
```

but when nothing is found, I get this error:

```
Warning:  mysql_result() [<a href='function.mysql-result'>function.mysql-result</a>]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 2 in
```

I still get the error even if I use something like `if (!empty($back))`

How can I avoid the error? Any alternative methods are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = 'some query...';
$result = mysql_query($q);

if($result === false){
      throw new Exception(mysql_error($connection));
 }
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     //Process Result
      $back = mysql_result($query, 0);
   } else {
      // empty Result Set
   }
```

Note the check on (! $result) -- if your $result is a boolean, it's certainly false, and it means there was a database error, meaning error is your query

Your error is caused by the fact that the query returned no rows - e.g. nothing matched.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the mysql_query() first and check if anything was returned (if $result) before calling mysql_result.

BTW you should be using mysqli_query, etc. these days the earlier version is insecure...